# Why does the Spotify client render certain pages completely black?

Tags: graphics, music, streaming, spotify, hardware-acceleration

Spotify starts up fine, but when navigating to certain sections of the app, instead of the expected content a black square is displayed. What is causing this issue and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

A while back, Spotify enabled hardware acceleration by default in the desktop client. On certain systems (not only Linux), incompatibility with the graphics drivers causes some content to fail to render. The suggested solution is to disable hardware acceleration in the clients' Preferences (Edit > Preferences):

[image]

Applying this change requires a restart of the Spotify client. If this causes a "Failed loading skin" error, uninstall spotify (`sudo apt-get remove spotify-client`) and remove /opt/Spotify (`sudo rm -rfv /opt/Spotify`). Reinstall Spotify (`sudo apt-get install spotify-client`) and the issue should be resolved; hardware acceleration should now be disabled.

Comment: seems not to work with spotify version 0.9.4.183.g644e24e0

the option is not available.

Comment: It's still there on 0.9.15.27.g87efe634 on Windows, it's right after the "Playback" section and before the "Cache" section. Seems odd that they would remove it only on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

to disable hardware acceleration on the linux client, do it using this command:

```
spotify --disable-gpu
```

For some reason, the option to disable hardware acceleration is not available in the latest version of spotify-client (linux). (My version Spotify version 1.1.84.716.gc5f8b819) on ubuntu 22.04.

I just realized that if you right click before opening the app there is an option called. (Also works for me)

```
"Launch using Discrete Graphics card"
```

I hope this helps,

All the best.